# How to use multiple imputed data for further analysis in SVM and ANN?

Tags: missing-data, imputation, r-mice

My original data contains some missing values and I used multiple imputation to fill them. My next objective is to use these data in SVM and ANN. I originally thought MI would give me a "pooled" completed dataset but it turned out that MI only gives pooled analysis results regarding the imputed datasets. So my questions are:
1) Is there any way, like any equation, I can use to aggregate the imputed datasets into one dataset and use it for further analysis;
2) If not, how should proceed my study using the multiple datasets.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is a general misunderstanding about MI.

The general process is supposed to be like this:

1. Multiple Imputation
2. Analysis for each imputed dataset
3. Pooling

If you would do the imputation and then merge all imputed dataset to one imputed dataset you loose all the benefit of MI. Then you could have just used any other imputation method. The idea is to perform your analysis for example 5 times, one time for each imputed dataset. Because you want to account for the different outcomes your analysis could have had with different imputed input datasets. Afterwards you pool / merge the results of your analysis.
The whole process is not so common in ML. But in your case you could for example use SVM on all 5 datasets and then afterwards compare the results / come up with a procedure to merge/combine the results.